# How does glRotate handle off glOrtho's?

Tags: c++, opengl

When I do something stupid like
*glOrtho(-2, 6, 0, 8, -4, 4);*
around what point would it rotate? Would it be around **0,0,0** still, or **2,4,0**?

Comment: That question is totally unclear, `glRotate` rotates always around the current orgigin.

Comment: What would the origin be in this case? 0,0,0 or 2,4,0?

Comment: @Binero: The origin is always 0,0,0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glOrtho` multiplies the current matrix with an orthographic matrix.  It doesn't add a rotation; rather, it is supposed to do an orthogonal projection.